# Apache not starting because of config

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, virtualhost

Im trying to setup a reverseproxy in apache, but when the following config is enabled it fails to start.
Without any error messages whatshowever.

Im not very experienced so this just be a dumb mistake.

when I run apachectl configtest it tells me that all syntax is OK

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName www.unifi.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com
            ServerAlias www.unifi.xxxxxxxxxxx.com
            Redirect / https://www.unifi.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerName www.unifi.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com
            ServerAlias www.unifi.xxxxxxxxxxx.com

            SSLEngine on
            SSLProxyEngine on
            SSLProxyVerify none
            SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
            SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
            SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

            ProxyRequests off

            ProxyPass       /  https://192.168.xxx.xxx:8443/
            ProxyPassReverse / https://192.168.xxx.xxx:8443/
            Header set Host www.unifi.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com
            RequestHeader set Host 192.168.xxx.xxx
            Header unset Referer
            RequestHeader unset Referer
    </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

`apachectl configtest` passes, so it must be a problem with your ssl config.

Look for an ssl error file and see what is in there.

Most systems have it in `/var/log/httpd` or `/var/log/apache2`

In other words, I'm not sure it's your proxy configuration causing your problems.